# Cygwin, SWIG, and Python

Tags: python, cygwin, swig

I want to use a DLL I created in SWIG using Cygwin from python, but it doesn't work outside of the implementation of python that cygwin provides. What's going on? When I'm in cygwin, I do:

```
  $python
    >>>import arraytest
```

And it works just fine.

When I move the DLL into the python path for python 3.2.3 (I'm using Windows), and try to use it, I get this error:

```
   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I know that it's in the correct path and that I'm referencing it the right way (because otherwise I get an "ImportError: No module named..." error.

I need this DLL to be usable from whatever Python platform, so if the cygwin-created DLL can only be used by cygwin, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

I think that a single DLL cannot be used by both the Cygwin Python and the standard (MSVC-compiled) Python for Windows. You should probably distribute two different DLLs, or just use MSVC Express to build the DLL.

Comment: Awww man I was hoping that wasn't the case! (Having trouble getting started with visual studio so now it's a matter of figuring out what i'm doing wrong there). Thank you for your response!

Comment: @djc how can I compile this for windows? I can't find an option to do it in Visual Studio